# ActiveMq and mosquitto bridge not working

Tags: activemq-classic, mosquitto

I am getting below error on activemq console when i am trying to connect from mosquitto to activemq.

```
WARN | Transport Connection to: tcp://192.168.0.27:48689 failed: java.io.IOException: Unknown data type: 77
```

MY setup is as below 
192.168.0.27 ---- Mosquitto broker with below configuration for bridge

```
connection try
try_private false
address 192.168.0.22:61616
username myuser
password mypassword
start_type automatic
clientid 1
notifications true
topic inbound/# in alpha/ beta/
topic outbound/# out harry/ larry
```

My ActiveMQ broker is 192.168.0.22 with TansportConnector  is as below

```
<transportConnectors>
        <transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireformat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
    </transportConnectors>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This won't work because the connector on the broker is being created as the OpenWire connector which only works with OpenWire clients.  You need to add an MQTT connector to your broker:

```
<transportConnectors>
    <transportConnector name="mqtt" uri="mqtt://0.0.0.0:1883?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireformat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
</transportConnectors>
```

Then you can configure you other MQTT resources to connect there.

Comment: Please mark this as resolved then if you got it working.